# Confused about pot odds

Tags: odds, no-limit, all-in, pot-odds

I wanted to practice my implied and pot odds calculating skills and found this website online
***http://www.philnolimits.com/uploads/8/1/8/9/8189328/practice_pot_odds_and_expected_value_problems.pdf***
And it had this problem which I think was wrong:

All In?
You have    $50 remaining   in  a   cash    game    and you flop    a   small   flush   draw.       There   is
$30 in  the pot and your    opponent    goes    all in.         Should  you call    with    your    flush   draw?
The only    way you can win is  to  hit the flush   on  the turn    or  the river.

The answer was right but the thought process looked flawed. It goes like:
*First, use the Rule    of  Four.       You have    9   outs    with    two cards   to  come.           9   x   4   =   36%.

You have    about   a   36% chance  of  making  your    flush   and winning the pot.*
$30  (pot)   +   $50 (his    bet)    +   $50 (your   call)   =   $130    total   pot.
*You have    to  call    $50 to  win $130.
$50 (your   call)   / $130  (total  pot after   your    call)   =   38%
So, by  a   slim    margin, you should  fold.*

I mean you shouldn't take into consideration your 50$ bet into the amount you win.
I think it should be like 30$ + 50$ = 80$ pot and you have to bet 50$, so your getting 8 to 5 odds to call there. Am wrong or is this article flawed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ratio vs Percentage in pots odds and hand odds](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/2970/ratio-vs-percentage-in-pots-odds-and-hand-odds)

Answer (score 5):

Here is another way to look at it:

```
Gained if you call and win: 30+50 = 80
Lost if you call and lose: 50
Your Equity = 0.36
EV = Equity(Gained when win) + (1-Equity)(Lost when lose)
EV = 0.36(80) + (1-.36)(50)
EV = 28.8 + -32
EV = -3.2
```

Plug in 0.38 for your equity and you will see that its indeed near a break-even call.

How did they get that formula?

```
Lets say:
E = Your Equity
P = Pot
B = Bet that your facing

Just like above...
EV = E(P + B) + (1-E)(-B)

Lets set EV to 0 (since we want to find out where the b/e call is) and solve for E  :
0 = E(P + B) + (1-E)(-B)
0 = EP + EB -B + EB
B = EP + EB + EB
B = E(P + B + B)

B / (P + B + B) = E
E = B / (P + B + B)
E = 50 / (30 + 50 + 50)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's a common misunderstanding. You can do it both ways, it's up to what's more convenient to you.

> European Way (include the amount you bet)

equity (%) = your_money/(pot+your_money) = 50 / 130 = 38%

> American Way (not include your bet)

equity (us) = your_money/pot = 50 / 80 = 5:8
==> meaning you will win 5 times and lose 8 = 38% (European)

The flush draw probability if you go all in from the flop is in European odds = 36%,
 but in US odds ~ 1:2.

The catch is to be consistent, so either calculate everything is US odds or European,up to you really ;)

**EDIT:** Lessharm has given the mathematical approach, which will clarify it more

Comment: Pot odds typically express as 8 : 5.   Same with sports betting.   Maywheather is 4 : 1.

Comment: For us in the east part of the Atlantic, it sounds really weird ;)

Answer (score -1):

When you go all-in there is no implied odds

On the flop if you go all in then you are not going to face another bet so you can go with the odds of the next two cards.

Hand odds = (1 - your probability) / (your probability)
You have 9 outs
Hand odds for one card is (45 - 9) / 9 = 4 : 1
But you have two cards to come so your hand odds are
(2/3) / (1/3) = 2 : 1
You can call a pot sized bet
35% is close enough to 1/3

Pot odds
You would be risking 50 to win 80 so your pot odds are 8 : 5 = 1.6 : 1
Your 50 that you get back is not a winning

Pot odds less than hand odds so you should not call
And you could be drawing dead to a bigger flush

Remember you go on the bottom (denominator) in hand and pot odds

[related](https://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/6903/pot-odds-equity-percentage-and-ratio-method/6906#6906)

Comment: DV what is the problem?  This is correct.  https://www.cardschat.com/odds-for-dummies.php